# Ability to alter my favorite sites in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

So I finally got my invitation (yay! It's awesome! Thanks!) and I'd like this first feature request to be typed from here.

I propose the ability to change the "favorite" sites, and also include meta sites in there.

Right now, I presume it's reading the list of sites ordered by reputation.  I propose the following:

- If I am a moderator on any site, those sites and their metas should come first.
- After that, ordered by reputation.
- The above is only the default order, and can be altered freely by the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now the situation is as you described, it's your top seven sites sorted by reputation.

We will hopefully soon offer the ability to control that completely, where you can add "pinned" sites and have them on the dashboard in any order you want, else it'll fall back to the current logic it has now.

We're currently trying to make sure that we do this in a way on the android app that matches what [we want to do on the network's new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign), after which this feature will come out on mobile.

Edit: I got too excited and ended up doing this earlier than expected. As of version 0.1.53 you can now tap on the "YOUR SITES" text on the left nav and you'll see something like this which allows you to pin sites to the left nav and modify their order:

[image]

Comment: Great can't wait for both to happen :) You guys are doing a great job, keep it up!